# Documentum integration with SDL Tridion

Tags: 2013-sp1

I need advice or suggestion on how to go with the Documentum integration with SDL Tridion 2013 sp1 any web link or document regarding the same .

Answer (score 7):

The was previously a [EMC Documentum Connector for SDL Tridion](http://www.emc.com/enterprise-content-management/emc-documentum-sdl-tridion/documentum-connector-for-sdl-tridion.htm) product that allowed two-way communication between the two repositories.

However, as noted on [the release announcement of SDL Tridion 2013 SP1](https://sdltridionworld.com/releases/release_news/sdltridion2013sp1-released.aspx) (the version that you are using) on SDL Tridion World:

> The SDL Tridion Connector 2011 for SharePoint and SDL Tridion
>   Connector for ECM Documentum are replaced by the SDL Tridion 
>   Connector 1.0 for CMIS

[CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) (Content Management Interoperability Services) is a standard that allows Content Management Systems (such as SDL Tridion and Documentum) to connect, and reference/share repository items, over the internet.

More details on SDL Tridion Connector 1.0 for CMIS (including installing, configuring and implementing) can be found in [the online SDL documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDLTridion_ECL_CMIS_10/concept_WelcomeCMIS).